# Problem with file IO streamreader + streamwriter C#

Tags: c#, file-io, streamreader, streamwriter

Hi guys I am kinda new to C#. I am trying to do some file io stuff. When I read and write it is only doing it on one line. Is there a way to advance the streamreader/streamwriter? It is for a school assignment. Here is what I have so far. Thanks very much.

```
enter code her class FileIO 
{
    public static void Save(ArrayList vehicleList)
    {

        StreamWriter streamWriter;
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Constants.fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(file);

        String typeOfVehicle = " ";
        String model = " ";
        String manufactuer = " ";
        Int32 year = 0;
        Int32 vin = 0;
        Double price = 0;
        String purchaseDate = " ";
        Int32 currentOdometerReading = 0;
        Double sizeOfEngine = 0;
        String typeOfMotorCycle = " ";
        Int32 numOfDoors = 0;
        String typeOfFuel = " ";
        Double cargoCapacity = 0;
        Double towingCapacity = 0;

        foreach (CommonItem vehicle in vehicleList)
        {
            typeOfVehicle = vehicle.TypeOfVehicle;
            model = vehicle.Model;
            manufactuer = vehicle.Manufactuer;
            year = vehicle.Year;
            vin = vehicle.Vin;
            price = vehicle.InitialPrice;
            purchaseDate = vehicle.PurchaseDate;
            currentOdometerReading = vehicle.CurrentOdometerReading;
            sizeOfEngine = vehicle.EngineSize;

            streamWriter.Write(typeOfVehicle + "~" + manufactuer + "~" + model + "~" + year.ToString() + "~" + vin.ToString() + "~" + price.ToString() + "~" + purchaseDate + "~" + currentOdometerReading.ToString() + "~" + sizeOfEngine.ToString() + "~");

            switch (typeOfVehicle)
            {
                case "Automobile":
                    numOfDoors = ((Automobile)vehicle).NumberOfDoors;
                    typeOfFuel = ((Automobile)vehicle).TypeOfFuel;
                    streamWriter.Write(numOfDoors + "~" + typeOfFuel + "~");
                    break;
                case "Motorcycle":
                    typeOfMotorCycle = ((Motorcycle)vehicle).Type;
                    streamWriter.Write(typeOfMotorCycle + "\n");
                    break;
                case "Truck":
                    cargoCapacity = ((Truck)vehicle).CargoCapacity;
                    towingCapacity = ((Truck)vehicle).TowingCapacity;
                    streamWriter.Write(cargoCapacity + "~" + towingCapacity);
                    break;
            }

            streamWriter.Write("\n");
        }
        streamWriter.Close();

    }

    public static ArrayList Load()
    {
        ArrayList vehicles = new ArrayList();
        FileStream file = new FileStream(Constants.fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(file);

        String typeOfVehicle = " ";
        String model = " ";
        String manufactuer = " ";
        Int32 year = 0;
        Int32 vin = 0;
        Double price = 0;
        String purchaseDate = " ";
        Int32 currentOdometerReading = 0;
        Double sizeOfEngine = 0;
        String typeOfMotorCycle = " ";
        Int32 numOfDoors = 0;
        String typeOfFuel = " ";
        Double cargoCapacity = 0;
        Double towingCapacity = 0;

        String tempString = " ";

        while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempString = streamReader.ReadLine()))
        {
            Int32 temp;
            String [] split = tempString.Split('~');
            temp = split.Length;

            typeOfVehicle = split[0];
            manufactuer = split[1];
            model = split[2];
            year = Convert.ToInt32(split[3]);
            vin = Convert.ToInt32(split[4]);
            price = Convert.ToDouble(split[5]);
            purchaseDate = split[6];
            currentOdometerReading = Convert.ToInt32(split[7]);
            sizeOfEngine = Convert.ToDouble(split[8]);

            if (typeOfVehicle == "Automobile")
            {
                numOfDoors = Convert.ToInt32(split[9]);
                typeOfFuel = split[10];
                Automobile car = new Automobile(manufactuer, model, year, vin, price, purchaseDate, currentOdometerReading, sizeOfEngine, numOfDoors, typeOfFuel);
                VehicleCount.IncreaseCarCount();
                vehicles.Add(car);
            }
            else if (typeOfVehicle == "Motorcycle")
            {
                typeOfMotorCycle = split[9];
                Motorcycle bike = new Motorcycle(manufactuer, model, year, vin, price, purchaseDate, currentOdometerReading, sizeOfEngine, typeOfMotorCycle);
                VehicleCount.IncreaseBikeCount();
                vehicles.Add(bike);
            }
            else
            {
                cargoCapacity = Convert.ToDouble(split[9]);
                towingCapacity = Convert.ToDouble(split[10]);
                Truck truck = new Truck(manufactuer, model, year, vin, price, purchaseDate, currentOdometerReading, sizeOfEngine, cargoCapacity, towingCapacity);
                VehicleCount.IncreaseTruckCount();
                vehicles.Add(truck);
            }
        }

        streamReader.Close();

        return vehicles;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> When I read and write it is only doing it on one line. Is there a way
>   to advance the streamreader/streamwriter?

Yes - use `streamWriter.WriteLine()` instead of `streamWriter.Write();`

What you are writing looks like data separated by "~" - you might want to look into writing out CSV = [comma-separated values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values), which is similar and pretty much standard.

Also instead of `ArrayList` you should use a strongly typed collection - in your case depending on your class structure you can use `List<Vehicle>` (if `Automobile` and `Motorcycle` both inherit from `Vehicle`).

Comment: Okay that fixed my writing issue. But when I am reading in it is still only reading in one line

Comment: How are you reading it in? What does the data look like if you open it with notepad?

Comment: Something like this : there is new lines between each one: Motorcycle~e~s~2000~12~12~1\1\2000~1~1~sport
Motorcycle~e~s~2000~12~12~1\1\2000~1~1~sport
Motorcycle~e~s~2000~12~12~1\1\2000~1~1~sport

Comment: And i have a method called load()

Comment: while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempString = streamReader.ReadLine()))

This loop is only iterating once.

Comment: @cody: make sure you don't have an empty line in your file - that would explain it. You might want to break apart that condition and specifically check for `tempString!=null`. Also remove the `Write('\n')` if you haven't already, always assemble your line in a string, then use `WriteLine()` to write it out.

Comment: @BrokenGlass I checked the file and when I enter more than one vehicle there is no extra empty lines. And in regards to the Write I changed that like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line

```
while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tempString = streamReader.ReadLine()))
```

The loop exits when it meets a blank line because IsNullOrEmpty method returns true. Try below instead..

```
while ((tempString = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
```